# i get the success message but nothing inserted in my mysql database

Tags: php, android

i get the success message, no errors but nothing inserted in my database and i'v tested my php file with postman and its working the row is added.
i'm new to android please help me thank u.

```html
<?php

@mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("advalio")or die(mysql_error());

if( isset($_POST['lat_gps']) && isset($_POST['lng_gps'])&& isset($_POST['azimut'])&& isset($_POST['support'])&& isset($_POST['hba'])
 && isset($_POST['type_antenne'])&& isset($_POST['antenne_vendor'])&& isset($_POST['tiltElec2G'])&& isset($_POST['tiltElec3G'])&& isset($_POST['tiltMec'])){
 
 $sql=  'SELECT id_visite FROM visite WHERE id_visite=(SELECT MAX(id_visite) FROM visite)';
 $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br />'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
 $data = mysql_fetch_array($req);
 
 mysql_free_result ($req);
 
 $sql1 = 'INSERT INTO configuration VALUES("","'.$data['id_visite'].'", "'.$_POST['lat_gps'].'", "'.$_POST['lng_gps'].'","'.$_POST['azimut'].'","'.$_POST['support'].'","'.$_POST['hba'].'",
 "'.$_POST['type_antenne'].'","'.$_POST['antenne_vendor'].'","'.$_POST['tiltElec2G'].'","'.$_POST['tiltElec3G'].'","'.$_POST['tiltMec'].'",0,1)';
  mysql_query ($sql1) or die ('Erreur SQL !'.$sql1.'<br />'.mysql_error());

 // on ferme la connexion à la base
 
 mysql_close();
}

 ?>
```

android activity

```html
package com.example.oumnia.advalio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AvOnglet2Activity extends Activity{
    EditText edazimut;
    EditText  edsupport;
    EditText  edhba;
    EditText edtypant;
    EditText edantven;
    EditText edtilelec2g;
    EditText edtilelec3g;
    EditText edtilmec;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.avonglet2_main);
        edazimut=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec11);
        edsupport=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec12);
        edhba=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec13);
        edtypant=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec14);
        edantven=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec15);
        edtilelec2g=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec16);
        edtilelec3g=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec17);
        edtilmec=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec18);


    }
    public void insert(View v){
        edazimut=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec11);
        edsupport=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec12);
        edhba=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec13);
        edtypant=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec14);
        edantven=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec15);
        edtilelec2g=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec16);
        edtilelec3g=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec17);
        edtilmec=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtSec18);

        String lng_gps = getIntent().getStringExtra("lng_gps");
        String lat_gps = getIntent().getStringExtra("lat_gps");
        String support  = edsupport.getText().toString();
        String hba  = edhba.getText().toString();
        String type_antenne  = edtypant.getText().toString();
        String antenne_vendor  = edantven.getText().toString();
        String tiltElec2G  = edtilelec2g.getText().toString();
        String tiltElec3G  = edtilelec3g.getText().toString();
        String tiltMec  = edtilmec.getText().toString();



        insertToDatabase(lat_gps,lng_gps,support,hba,type_antenne,antenne_vendor,tiltElec2G,tiltElec3G,tiltMec);
    }

    private void insertToDatabase(final String  lat_gps,final String lng_gps,final String support,final String hba,
                                  final String type_antenne,final String antenne_vendor,final String tiltElec2G,
                                  final String tiltElec3G,final String tiltMec){
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String paramlat_gps = params[0];
                String paramlng_gps = params[1];
                String paramsupport = params[2];
                String paramhba = params[3];
                String paramtype_antenne = params[4];
                String paramantenne_vendor = params[5];
                String paramtiltElec2G = params[6];
                String paramtiltElec3G = params[7];
                String paramtiltMec = params[8];


                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat_gps", lat_gps));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng_gps",  lng_gps));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("support", support));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hba", hba));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type_antenne", type_antenne));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("antenne_vendor", antenne_vendor));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tiltElec2G",tiltElec2G));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tiltElec3G",tiltElec3G));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tiltMec",tiltMec));


                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://192.168.x.x/ADvalio/configAvSec1.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "success";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(lat_gps,lng_gps,support,hba,type_antenne,antenne_vendor,tiltElec2G,tiltElec3G,tiltMec);

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't seem to send `azimut`

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the problem.